# Display the command that is being executed in cshell

Tags: csh

I am using csh where i want to display the command that is being executed.

I can see find something like `set -x` placing at the beginning of the script. But it seems to only work for bash. In cshell i am getting following error.

```
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
Failed
```

Is there any way to display the command the is being executed in cshell. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your c-shell script using `csh -v`. This will display each line of the script before executing it. This is useful for debugging c-shell scripts.